# Is $\left(-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}+\nabla^2\right)\phi=0$ same as $\partial_\mu\left( g^{\mu\nu}\sqrt{-g} \partial_\nu\phi\right)=0$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, special-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I'm a beginner when we talk about General Relativity, right now I reading an article about gravitational waves but I need help here. Until I know the equation that describes a gravitational wave is,

\begin{equation}
\left(-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}+\nabla^2\right)\phi=0,
\end{equation}
where $\phi$ is a scalar field.
It is the wave equation in 3+1D, but in the article says the equation that describes a gravitational wave is,

\begin{equation}
\partial_\mu\left( g^{\mu\nu}\sqrt{-g} \partial_\nu\phi\right)=0.
\end{equation}

**My question is,** they are both the same equations, aren't they? Is the first one a special case of the second equation? If that is the case, then how can we obtain the first from the second one?

Comment: The second equation is the scalar wave equation in any background metric. The first equation is a special case of the second when applied to flat metric background.

Comment: The GR equations are second order, coupled and non linear, so you need to work them out by treating them as the flat metric $\eta_{\mu v} $ with perturbations, does  that make any sense to you?   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave

Comment: What is phi in the second equation? Keep in mind the general relativity equations, even as perturbations on a flat spacetime, are tensorial, spin 2

Answer (score 5):

[EDITED]

Almost. The "correct" form of the second equation is

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\ \partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{-g}\ g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}\ \phi)=0
$$

which is to say

$$
\text{div}\ \text{grad}\ \ \phi=0
$$

if you are familiar with the gradient and divergence operators in curved spacetimes, or

$$
\Delta\ \phi=0
$$
if you are familiar with the Laplace-Beltrami operator on curved spacetimes. Of course the former is verified if and only if $\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{-g}\ g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}\ \phi)=0$, so the statement is indeed correct. The wave equation in flat spacetime is indeed the particular form of the above equation in flat coordinates, which are such that, with $x^{0}=t$, $x^{i}=\vec{x}$,

$$
g_{00}=-1\qquad \qquad g_{0i}=0\qquad g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}
$$
with $i=1,2,3$. Then you have

$$
g^{00}=-1\qquad \qquad g^{0i}=0\qquad g^{ij}=\delta^{ij}
$$
and
$$
\det g=-1
$$

and you can see for yourself that the equation reduces to the wave equation.

$$
$$

Now as for gravitational waves, they don't actually obey the wave equation. It is possible to use the so called "weak field approximation" (you have a metric of the form $g=\eta+h$, with $\eta$ the Minkowski metric and $h$ a small perturbation of $\eta$), together with a special choice of coordinates, in order to get an equation which has the same form as the wave equation. In this case, the unknown function(s) would be the $h_{\mu\nu}$'s, so that you have

$$
\eta^{\sigma\lambda}\ \partial_{\sigma}\partial_{\lambda}\ h_{\mu\nu}=\bigg(-\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}+\nabla^{2}\bigg)\ h_{\mu\nu}=0
$$

But the said special choice of coordinates brings with it some additional equations:

$$
\eta^{\mu\sigma}\ \partial_{\mu}h_{\sigma\nu}=0\qquad\qquad \eta^{\mu\nu}h_{\mu\nu}=0
$$

Which is to say, $h_{\mu\nu}$ is divergence-free (the first one) and trace-free (the second one). Notice that, as I said, the former only are an approximation to the full equation, which is nonlinear.

Comment: Shouldn't the outer div produce a covariant derivative?

Comment: Yes, it does. In fact it produces two covariant derivatives: $\text{grad}\ \text{div}=\nabla_{\mu}\nabla^{\mu}$. (On functions of course)

Comment: Sorry, it is the other way round: $\text{div}\ \text{grad}$

Comment: @SeanLake: yes, $\nabla^{a}\nabla_{a}\phi = \nabla^{a}\partial_{a}\phi = g^{ab} \partial_{a}\partial_{b}\phi - g^{ab}\Gamma_{ab}{}^{c}\partial_{c}\phi$  All that's left is to work out the equivalency of $-g^{ab}\Gamma_{ab}{}^{c}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_{a}\left(g^{ac}\sqrt{-g}\right)$